# Clone enterprise repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

I'm trying to clone a private github enterprise repository using jenkins job builder. How do I provide the username/password or API token of the github user so that jenkins can clone the directory?

Doing all this through an ansible playbook, so manually adding the git credentials to jenkins is not possible

Comment: If you use your enterprise jenkins server, you can contact with the jenkins admin to add the credential in Jenkins -> System menu from Jenkins Web UI

Comment: I’m using enterprise GitHub. Jenkins is just the public version

Answer (score 0):

You have to use credentials plugin for that. Here I am attaching the link to it. Feel free to explore around it. Hope this helps. If you find any trouble, comment here.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin